# How do I affect the contents of multiple dictionaries or objects iteratively from within a loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a pen-and-paper RPG system I know as a springboard for learning Python. I want to be able to use an object to represent a character, with all the stats that implies.  I'm trying to use `for` and `while` loops to do things like determine number of actions per turn (based on individual speed) and the actions they take.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to refer to the object within the loop so that Python goes through and sequentially affects each of the objects the way I'd want.

```
class char:            
    counter = 0         #char counter to keep track of the nbr of doodz
    Asidecounter = 0
    Bsidecounter = 0
    def __init__(self,name,side,Spd,cSPD,DEF,HP,cHP):
        self.name=name      
        self.side=side
        self.Spd=Spd
        self.cSPD=cSPD
        self.DEF=DEF
        self.HP=HP
        self.cHP=cHP
        char.counter+=1    
        if self.side == "a":
            char.Asidecounter+=1
        else:
            char.Bsidecounter+=1
        activechars.append(name)

activechars=[]
defeatedchars=[]
```

Okay, this gives us a character and some stats.  (I tried to omit some extra stats here.)  I have a counter for which side they're on, a total character count and so on every time I add a character to the mix.  The problem is, then I want to determine the total # of moves available to be distributed among however many characters, I try to do something like this and it just doesn't work for me:

```
movecount=0
for i in range(len(activechars)):
    movepick = activechars[i]
    movecount+=movepick.Spd
```

You can see where I'm going here.  I'd like to do something similar for attacks, special powers usage, whatever--put it in a loop but then call (and change) object-specific values from inside the loops, and I just don't know how to.

I've tried this with dictionaries instead of defined "char" objects; e.g.

```
hero={"Spd":4,"cSPD":4,"DEF":8,"HP":10,"cHP":10}
```

...and then rewrite the loops for a dictionary instead.  But it's not working either way.

(Also, I've been told that I don't follow Python capitalization conventions, for which I apologize.)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: If you want the TOTAL speed for all the chaacters, that's just `movecount = sum(k.Spd for k in activechars)`.  Any time you write `for i in range(len(xxx))`, there's a better way to do it, usually by `for k in xxx:`.

Comment: HOWEVER, your `activechars` list should contain `char` objects, not their names.  And those lists should be created OUTSIDE of the class.  The character objects should not need to know they are part of any list.

Comment: Also, the last 5 lines of your `__init__` are not indented properly.  They should be part of the function, and right now they are not.

Comment: Thank you all!  I have many new questions now.
1. The error I get is "movecount+=movepick["Spd"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers"
2. I think this is the first time I've ever seen a "for k in xxx" loop.  Searching it just brings up a series of articles about for loops.  Is "k" a different iterator than i?  Any direction there would help.
3. How do I contain objects inside of the list like that?  Do they keep their value references consistent, i.e. if I reduce the object's HP in the list, does the object outside the list lose HP?
4. I thought that was working as is but thank you!

Comment: I ran out of space but thank you all for your thoughts!  I'm enjoying this process, and also I'll take all the help I can get.  This is much appreciated.

Comment: Also, @TimRoberts you're right, I checked my code and I copied the indents incorrectly.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: There is one object for each character, no matter how many references there are.  Python doesn't create copies; you have to go out of your way to do that.  `for` loops are absolutely fundamental to Python.  You need to read about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close, it appears to be a small issue.  Running your code and created `char` objects, I noticed you're saving the object's *name* attribute only into the list - for instance, "lancelot" instead of something like `<__main__.char at 0x1e5770a9f48>`.  Simply change the last line to append `self` instead of name (also check indentation).

```
class char:                                                            
    counter = 0         #char counter to keep track of the nbr of doodz
    Asidecounter = 0                                                   
    Bsidecounter = 0                                                   
    def __init__(self,name,side,Spd,cSPD,DEF,HP,cHP):                  
        self.name=name                                                 
        self.side=side                                                 
        self.Spd=Spd                                                   
        self.cSPD=cSPD                                                 
        self.DEF=DEF                                                   
        self.HP=HP                                                     
        self.cHP=cHP                                                   
        char.counter+=1                                                
        if self.side == "a":                                           
            char.Asidecounter+=1                                       
        else:                                                          
            char.Bsidecounter+=1                                       
        activechars.append(self)                                       
                                                                       
activechars=[]                                                         
defeatedchars=[]
```

Comment: Hah!  Aww sheesh. I hoped I was missing something basic, since in theory this made sense to me.

Thank you so much!  This has been driving me nuts for over a week now.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: No problem - you had already laid all the groundwork for what you wanted.  Glad it worked out